# switch vectors of a pointer to a object c++

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, constructor

I want to move a certain pointer to an object from one vector to another, here's a bit of my current code:

```
person * room::remove_person(const int &id) {

 person* new_person;
 for (auto p = ppl_room.begin(); p != ppl_room.end(); p++) {
     if ((*p)->getID() == id) {
         new_person = new person(*p); 
     }

 }
 return new_person;
```

}

I have a copy constructor but I just can't retrieve the pointer to the object from the vector to then create a new one and return it...
Any tips on how to make this code work?

note: the vector is a vector of pointers of person

Comment: "I just can't" isn't a scientific problem statement. Please try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that we're talking about a `std::vector<Person*>` then you just need to erase the correct iterator and add the item to another vector, there is no need to copy the actual person through dynamic allocation and copy constructor. Eg:

```
std::vector<Person*> from, to;

int id;
auto it = std::find_if(from.begin(), from.end(), [id](const Person& p) { return p->getID() == id; });
if (it != from.end())
{
  to.push_back(*it);
  from.erase(it);
}
```